# How to wrap an element with a div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is to wrap all my `p` tags in a special div having a class p_wrapper. I want something like this:(For all elements not only for `p` and `div`)

```
$('p').wrappAll('.p_wrapper')
```

I should get this HTML:

### Before

```
<p>This is a paragraph!</p>
<p>This is another paragraph!</p>
```

### After

```
<div class="p_wrapper"> <p>This is a paragraph!</p> </div>
<div class="p_wrapper"> <p>This is another paragraph!</p> </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("p").wrap($("<div/>").addClass("p_wrapper"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aXwDs/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('p').wrap('<div class="p_wrapper"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
$('p').wrap('<div class="p_wrapper">');
```